# Display image using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display image using css. But it is not display anyway. please help me. My code is :

```css
//styles.css

table tr td span.glyphicon-eye-open{
 background: url("../images/private-eye.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
//Register.php

<form method="post" id="form1">
<table align="center" width="45%" cellpadding="7px">
<tr>
<td><label>*</label><input type="text" name="email" placeholder=" Your Email" value="<?=$email?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>*</label> <input type="password" name="pass" id="passwordfield" placeholder=" Your Password" value="<?=$password?>"/>
<span class="glyphicon-eye-open"></span>  
</td>
  <tr>
<td><button type="submit" name="btn_Register">Register</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I also has included
'link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" type="text/css" /'
in head with tags

Comment: "Not display" doesn't give much information. Are you sure the image is placed at the relative path you're pointing at? Try checking Network tab in Dev Tools on Chrome or Firezilla in Firefox.

Comment: I placed image in separate 'images' folder, which in given path is true.

Comment: @Sudip977 Try something like this then: 'images/private-eye.png' for ur background: url

Comment: @NickParsons but folder is not in 'css' folder

Comment: @Sudip977 Ah, ok. Some of the answers bellow may looks like they will work though :)

Comment: That is because your span has no height at all. Every span has no height until you insert some text in it or edit its height via CSS.

Answer (score 5):

That is because your span has no height at all. Every span has no height until you insert some text in it or edit its height via CSS. For example, I've put some text in here, like so:

```css
span.glyphicon-eye-open {
    background: url("http://beerhold.it/320/200") no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
//Register.php

<form method="post" id="form1">
<table align="center" width="45%" cellpadding="7px">
<tr>
<td><label>*</label><input type="text" name="email" placeholder=" Your Email" value="<?=$email?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>*</label> <input type="password" name="pass" id="passwordfield" placeholder=" Your Password" value="<?=$password?>"/>
<span class="glyphicon-eye-open">@@@</span>  
</td>
  <tr>
<td><button type="submit" name="btn_Register">Register</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this line

```
<span class="glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
```

to:

```
<span class="glyphicon-eye-open">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

**DEMO**

```css
span.glyphicon-eye-open {
 background: url("http://previews.123rf.com/images/arnau2098/arnau20981503/arnau2098150300166/37873708-small-squares-background-color-Stock-Photo.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
//Register.php

<form method="post" id="form1">
<table align="center" width="45%" cellpadding="7px">
<tr>
<td><label>*</label><input type="text" name="email" placeholder=" Your Email" value="<?=$email?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>*</label> <input type="password" name="pass" id="passwordfield" placeholder=" Your Password" value="<?=$password?>"/>
<span class="glyphicon-eye-open">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>  
</td>
  <tr>
<td><button type="submit" name="btn_Register">Register</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It now works fine using following css code :

```
table tr td span.glyphicon-eye-open{
background: url("../images/private-eye.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
/*width:50px;
height:50px;*/
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
padding-bottom:2px;
```

}

Comment: I have also used width and hieght of span, but not working.

Comment: It also works when I gives sufficient number of &nbsp; between <span> and </span>

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
.glyphicon-eye-open{
background: url("../images/private-eye.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Make sure your css is included